# How to download specific version file from s3 using transfer utility

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services

I am unable to download file of a specific version from AWS using transfer utility. Versioning is enabled on S3. Unable to find where to set file version in S3 transfer utility. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Which transfer utility are you using, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, S3 TransferUtility does not support downloading a specific version of a file. We have taken this as a feature request and will update this thread once we provide a way to do so.